# CairoSharp Nuget package does not find cairo.dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cairo

since I updated CairoSharp Nuget package from version 1.15.6 to version 3.22.24.37 in my program, the program does not work anymore. An error is produced: *"DllNotFoundException: Cairo"*. I have not found any information yet. How can I fix the problem?

1. I have also referenzed Cairo Nuget Packet;
2. I have copied runtime directory from cairo.dll to output directory;
3. I have copied cairo.dll to output directory;
4. I am developing under Windows 10 Pro. I have tried this on other computers with Windows 7;
5. I have created new user account where the name contains no space;
6. I've tried using netstandard, core or framework;
7. I tried out any version 3.x.x of CairoSharp;
8. I installed gtk...

nothing helped :-(

```
string path = "test1.svg";
SvgSurface svgSurfaceTest1 = new SvgSurface(path, 500, 500);
Context kontext1 = new Context(svgSurfaceTest1);
this.test1(kontext1);
```

at

```
SvgSurface svgSurfaceTest1 = new SvgSurface (path, 500, 500);
```

an error is thrown and the program breaks with Exception:
*"System.TypeInitializationException" 
"type initializer for Cairo.NativeMethods has caused an exception."
Inner exception
DllNotFoundException: Cairo*